# Add image in email that should be visible in Body

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Below code is with error and I cannot identify as a newbie, listing what issues I am facing

1.) Compile Error : Expected End With
2.) Image is not Visible in Outlook Body

Please advise

```
Sub EmailwithImage2() 
Dim OutlookApp As Object 
Dim MItem As Object 
Dim email_ As String 
Dim email2_ As String 
Dim cc As String 
Dim subject_ As 
String Dim body_ As String

Fname = XXXXXXXXXX

'Create Outlook object Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

'Create Mail Item and send it 
Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0) 
With MItem 
.To = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B1").Value 
.cc = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value 
.Subject = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value 
.Attachments.Add Fname, 1, 0 
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<img src=’cid:city.jpg’" & "width=’520' height=’750’>
" _

.Display

MsgBox ("you Mail has been sent to " & SendID)

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code misses an `End With` before `MsgBox`. And it needs `Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")` before `Set MItem = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)`.  `SendID` is not declared and it does not take a value. These modifications only to make the code workink. `.HTMLBody` needs a real `src` for `city.jpg`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to make sure you create a well-formed HTML document before setting to the `HTMLBody` property:

```
.HTMLBody = .HTMLBody & "<img src=’cid:city.jpg’" & "width=’520' height=’750’>"
```

It seems you need to find the place where the image should be inserted. At least it should be added before the closing `</body>` tag in the HTML markup.

Second, you need to make sure the image is added as a hidden attachment and the CID property is set correctly and corresponds to the one you use in the HTML markup.

```
Const PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001E"        
Const PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x7FFE000B" 

...

Set oPA = Attachment.PropertyAccessor            
oPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "city.jpg"            
oPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACHMENT_HIDDEN, True
```

Third - pay attention to the apostrophe (' or ’) character used in the code.

```
"<img src='cid:city.jpg' width='520' height='750'>"
```

Comment: Perfect , Well Noted !!! . However 1 quick question , with these changes , the Image still does not appear , when running this value as " -1" is displayed instead of the Image

Comment: Eugene , will trial and error based on your input , it finally works and sorted. Couldn't be more satisfied to see smething works withour error !!!! Thanks you so much. Much appreciated

Comment: Great! It makes sense to mark the post as the answer.